# How to properly set Column Width upon creating Excel file? (Column properties)

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am using standard library

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

And this is how I create Excel, just small part of code:

```
//Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel._Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//add data 
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Student1";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Student2";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Student3";
```

The problem is that sometimes size of cell can be smaller that text`s size. I tried this one:

```
Excel.Range chartRange;
chartRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 31.43;
```

It works fine, but I need to set this property for each column separately. How I can I do that?

Comment: better learn to save macros. that way you will have the code of ALL you need. I dont know it what I did in my answer I saved a macro and give you my result. it is really easy you just start  recording, do what you want to record in excel, and then you got the code of waht you did. its so powerfull and usefull

Comment: Thank you for advise, I found pretty nice article about it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/09/28/converting-a-vba-macro-to-c-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I normally do this in VB and its easier because Excel records macros in VB. So I normally go to Excel and save the macro I want to do.

So that's what I did now and I got this code:

```
Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 17.29;

Range("E3").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid;
Range("E3").Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic;
Range("E3").Interior.Color = 65535;
Range("E3").Interior.TintAndShade = 0;
Range("E3").Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0;
```

I think you can do something like this:

```
xlWorkSheet.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = 18;
```

For your last question what you need to do is loop trough the columns you want to set their width:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // this will apply it from col 1 to 10
{
    xlWorkSheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth = 18;
}
```

Comment: `xlWorkSheet.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = 18;` this is work as should ))

Comment: Doesn't work for me; this code (_xlSheet is my Worksheet) recognizes no "ColumnWidth" member:
xlSheet.Columns[ITEMDESC_COL].

Comment: And now it works (compiles, anyway - haven't tested it yet); I've got this in a for loop:
_xlSheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth = 12.75;
Why the difference between these two instances, I don't know...

Comment: for me, its strange. xlWorkSheet.Columns[rowindex, columnindex] ask for row and column index

Answer (score 38):

I did it this way:

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
var xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item[1];
xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

With this way, columns always fit to text width inside cells.

Hope it helps to someone!

Comment: Exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: I like this but take note it depends on existing content so add your content before calling AutoFit() .

Answer (score 5):

**Use this One**

```
 ((Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[1, 1]).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 10;
```

Answer (score 4):

This link explains how to apply a cell style to a range of cells: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1hh9fza.aspx

See this snippet:

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange rangeStyles =
this.Controls.AddNamedRange(this.Range["A1"], "rangeStyles");

rangeStyles.Value2 = "'Style Test";
rangeStyles.Style = "NewStyle";
rangeStyles.Columns.AutoFit();
```

Answer (score 4):

I have change all columns width in my case as

```
            worksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 7;
            worksheet.Columns[2].ColumnWidth = 15;
            worksheet.Columns[3].ColumnWidth = 15;
            worksheet.Columns[4].ColumnWidth = 15;
            worksheet.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = 18;
            worksheet.Columns[6].ColumnWidth = 8;
            worksheet.Columns[7].ColumnWidth = 13;
            worksheet.Columns[8].ColumnWidth = 17;
            worksheet.Columns[9].ColumnWidth = 17;
```

Note: Columns in worksheet start with 1 not from 0 as in Arrary.

Answer (score 1):

Excel ColumnWidth from dataGridView:

```
           foreach (DataGridViewColumn co in dataGridView1.Columns)
           { worksheet.Columns[co.Index + 1].ColumnWidth = co.Width/8; }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this snippet: (C#)

```
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla;
    Workbook wb;
    Worksheet ws;
    Range rg;
    ..........

        xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;
        rg = (Range)ws.Cells[1, 2];
        rg.ColumnWidth = 10;
        rg.Value2 = "Frequency";
        rg = (Range)ws.Cells[1, 3];
        rg.ColumnWidth = 15;
        rg.Value2 = "Impudence";
        rg = (Range)ws.Cells[1, 4];
        rg.ColumnWidth = 8;
        rg.Value2 = "Phase";
```